# ui problems when changing canvas localScale in coroutine in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, coroutine

I got a problem when I was changing the localScale of Canvas.
First of all, I want to design a function of to buy equipments in a tank war game, so I add a canvas to show the equipments. The structure of the canvas shows as follows:
[canvas ui structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUh6p.png)

At the beginning of the game, I change the localScale of the canvas from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1) over a period of time in a coroutine. The code shows as follows:

```cs
private IEnumerator DampCanvas(){
        float dis = Vector3.Distance (rect.localScale, Vector3.one);
        while (dis >= threshold) {
            rect.localScale = 
                Vector3.SmoothDamp (rect.localScale, Vector3.one, ref eqpsSmoothVec, eqpsSmoothTime);
            dis = Vector3.Distance (rect.localScale, Vector3.one);
            yield return null;
        }
        rect.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
```

The coroutine works ok, but I did something as folows before the coroutine:

- Add all equipments of default choosen type(Attack here) on the ui.
- Add all equipments of the current tank has bought on the ui

But the problems is the equipments had added on the ui do not show, but I do see the ui object in Hierarchy view.

[beginning of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7r0P.png)

[hierarchy view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QLiO.png)

I just learn unity for a short time and I don't konw what happened.Can anybody help me?

Comment: I would check that the not shown gamobjects are enabled (enable checkbox at the top left of the inspector) + their render componenets are enabled too. Also that they dont have any parent with scale = (0,0,0) in the scene hierarchy (transform parameters are parent relative, so if a parent has a scale of (0,0,0) this will be passed down to children, so children wont show)

Comment: @RustyBucketBay thank you !!! Just as you said, the localScale of equipments added is (0,0,0), passed down from the canvas. It works well now. Thank you !!!

Comment: I'm glad that helped. You can give that as the accepted anwer if that worked ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check that the not shown gamobjects are enabled (enable checkbox at the top left of the inspector) + their render componenets are enabled too. Also that they dont have any parent with scale = (0,0,0) in the scene hierarchy (transform parameters are parent relative, so if a parent has a scale of (0,0,0) this will be passed down to children, so children wont show)